# How to get a handle to the TableView from the controller in scalafx

Tags: scala, tableview, scalafx

I'm trying to find some sample code to update my TableView from inside my controller. If possible I want to make my TableView with fxml.

```
def addPerson(event: ActionEvent) {
  // how do I access my TableView items?
}
```

My TableView looks like:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView"></TableView>
```

Also, what's a good way to interactively inspect stage objects and methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use it, you need to pass it in as a parameter which will be shown below :

```
@sfxml
class PersonOverviewController(

    private val tableView : TableView[S] //S -> The type of the objects contained within the TableView items list.

    ) {

    def addPerson(event: ActionEvent) {
        // do whatever you want here with tableView
        val selectedIndex = tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndex.value //just for example 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set the fx:controller to it? It should be something like this `fx:controller="your.package.to.ControllerClass"` in your .fxml

Comment: The full length will be like : 
`<AnchorPane ........ fx:controller="your.package.to.ControllerClass">
 <children> </children> </AnchorPane>`

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think I almost got it. what goes inside of [T] though?

Comment: It was parametric polymorphism. Says in the table you are trying to show the type Person, then it should be `TableView[Person]`. It is the same as in Java <> for example LinkedList type of Integer will goes like `LinkedList<Integer>` .

Comment: I gave an upvote but I'm still getting errors: `value selectedIndex is not a member of javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel[sfxml.Person]` - maybe you  can give a better example?

Comment: May I know if you import the javafx library or scalafx library? selectedIndex method is belongs to `scalafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel` but not javafx's equivilent. Usually what we will do is we will import the scalafx's library, and import this : `import scalafx.Includes._` so that we can use both from scalafx and javafx

Comment: Thanks, that's working for me now with that import line.